# Avoiding primitive obsession in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, primitive

From http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

```
data Person = Person { name :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     } deriving (Show)
```

In a real application, using primitives like String and Int for name and age would constitue primitive obsession, a code smell. (also obviously Date born is preferable to Int age but let's ignore that) Instead, one would prefer something like

```
newtype Person = Person { name :: Name  
                        , age :: Age  
                        } deriving (Show)
```

In an OO language this would look something like

```
class Person {
  Name name;
  Age age;
  Person(Name name, Age age){
    if (name == null || age == null)
      throw IllegalArgumentException();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Name extends String {
  Name(String name){
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || name.length() > 100)
      throw IllegalArgumentException();
    super(name);
  }
}

class Age extends Integer {
  Age(Integer age){
    if (age == null || age < 0)
      throw IllegalArgumentException();
    super(age);
  }
}
```

But how is the same achieved in idiomatic, best practice Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `Name` abstract and provide a smart constructor. This means that you do not export the `Name` data constructor, and provide a `Maybe`-returning constructor instead:

```
module Data.Name
( Name -- note: only export type, not data constructor
, fromString
, toString
) where

newtype Name = Name String

fromString :: String -> Maybe Name
fromString n | null n         = Nothing
             | length n > 100 = Nothing
             | otherwise      = Just (Name n)

toString :: Name -> String
toString (Name n) = n
```

It is now impossible to construct a `Name` value of the wrong length outside of this module.

For `Age`, you could do the same thing, or use a type from `Data.Word`, or use the following inefficient but guaranteed non-negative representation:

```
data Age = Zero | PlusOne Age
```

Comment: would you mind elaborating on the differences between do the same thing, use type from Data.Word or the inefficient suggestion? Maybe also Liquid Haskell?

Comment: Exposing a smart constructor for `Age` is some work; you have to create a newtype and two functions; but it's efficient and easy to use. `Data.Word` is just an unsigned integer, like `uint` in C#. There's little benefit to using the `Zero`/`PlusOne` representation, really. I know very little about Liquid Haskell, but in F*, which also features refinement types, you would write `type Age = i : int { i >= 0 }` and the type checker will reject your program when it isn't 100% sure that the age you pass is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: I know this is just a silly example, but a lot of people make the real-world mistake of setting a length limit for names that's too short to handle all the names people actually have. Some limits are reasonable to avoid DOS attacks and such, but I'd be very suspicious of a name length limit under 256 characters or so, and if I were designing the system I'd want to consult an expert to make sure that was enough.

Answer (score 2):

This may be code smell in some languages, but it's not usually considered one in Haskell. You have to choose a concrete representation of a name and birth date *somewhere*, and the datatype declaration of `Person` is probably the best place to do it. In Haskell, the usual way to keep other code from depending on the name representation would be to make `Person` abstract. Instead of exposing the `Person` constructor, expose functions for creating, modifying, and inspecting `Person` values.

Comment: In my experience, virtually all devs and codebases in all languages prefer primitives for everything, and use variable names and inline validations rather than classes/types to indicate and validate what things are. They'd say my example was class/type obsession and call that a code smell.

Comment: @fred, it really depends on context and how the program grows. Premature abstraction and premature generalization can waste a lot of time if your initial guesses are wrong. `Person` seems like a fairly reasonable base abstraction, but again, that depends on the program.

Comment: Ridiculous. Haskell have phantom types, expressive polymorphism, smart constructors, exposing types without constructors. All the things to effectively deal with primitive obsession!

Primitive obsession - when in memory representation differ in any way from legitimate domain data+behaviour.

(E.g. absolute size and relative size will be represented by the same values in computer memory, however confusing one with other will have dire consequences. Add phantom type. Hakell will point those mistakes out)

Comment: @przemo_li, I don't understand what point you're trying to make.

Comment: It was attempt at hyperbole ;) But I do see your point, one could move validity checks to Person without loosing much.  -- That beeing said, moving validity checks from Person to Name and Age would allow to simplify tests. If Name and Age is always correct, there is nothing to test in Person, because valid Person is a combination of any Name with any Age.